# Show this form is locally exact and not globally exact.

Tags: differential-forms, curves

There is an example on DoCarmo (Differential Forms and Applications) that they show that 
$$ \omega = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy $$
is locally exact but not in their entire domain ($\mathbb{R}-\{ 0\} $).

I can see that in the path $(cos(t),sin(t)), t \in [0,2\pi]$ the integral is $2\pi$ so is not exact, but I don't understand why that form is locally exact. They show that is close (using that $d \omega = 0$). But why that implies that $\omega$ is exact?

Help with this please.

Comment: The Poincare Lemma says that if $\omega$ is closed, then it is *locally* exact. But you don't need the strength of the Poincare Lemma for this standard example; it is enough to note that in a sufficiently small ball around any point $(x_0, y_0)$, $\omega$ equals $d\theta$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle. The trouble is that $\theta$ cannot be defined globally.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528860/confusion-about-a-particular-differential-form-being-exact